# Does the discussion about new table support in main meta apply to chem SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, formatting, markdown

A new table format supported by markdown is discussed in meta, as you might have become aware from links to [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/feature-preview-table-support?cb=1)

Inserting a table appears to be as simple as inserting e.g. the following:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

This does not render properly on Chemistry SE (or SO, I'm assuming not on other SEs either) of course. Chemistry SE uses MathJax to display tables.

Any comments on this feature? Is this markdown not available here (will it ever)?

Comment: See your link: "After that, we're letting the feature sink in for a bit and gather more feedback before rolling it out network-wide to all sites across the Stack Exchange network. We're hoping to roll it out the week of 2020-12-07."

Comment: @Loong Thank you!

Comment: Oh well... Something more to worry about... I've worked with GitHub tables and found it difficult and underwhelming; so let's just hope for the best.

Comment: Interestingly, the table in this post renders for me in the edit window, but not when viewing it directly.

Comment: @Tyberius yes, a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the comments: I'm not sure, but I would guess that posts that predate the introduction of Markdown tables might not be automatically rendered as such. From [previous posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/312770), I infer that SE probably has a way of doing this.

On the other hand, when you edit, the post preview is updated on the fly, so probably by default uses all the latest features.

I copied the source of your table above, and you can see it works perfectly fine in this answer.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Editing your post and saving it might force the table to show, since the "edited" date would be pushed forward to after the introduction of Markdown tables.

Comment: Yes, making an edit and re-saving updated the display.

Comment: I've changed this to completed now and edited the question to include `code`. I guess they worked out the things to do to make this work …